# Return rows where consecutive values meet criterion

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `df`. I would like to return a vector `result` that indicates which rows meet the following criterion: at least 2 consecutive values in that row are lower than -1.7.

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V2=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V3=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V4=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V5=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V6=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V7=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V8=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V9=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V10=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5))
rownames(df) <- c(seq(1976,1985,1))
```

The result would be a vector:

```
result <- c(1977,1979,1980,1982,1983,1985)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to loop through the rows with `apply`, create a logical condition with `rle`, check if there are `any` TRUE elements that have `lengths` more than 1, extract the `names`

```
names(which(apply(df, 1, function(x) with(rle(x < - 1.7), any(lengths[values] > 1)))))
#[1] "1977" "1979" "1980" "1982" "1983" "1985"
```

---

Or a better approach is to vectorize it by placing two logical matrices (i.e. remove the first column of the dataset, check whether it is less than -1.7, similarly remove the last column and do the same), `Reduce` it to a single logical `matrix` by checking whether the corresponding elements are `TRUE`, get the `rowSums`, if the value is greater than 0, we extract the row names

```
names(which(rowSums(Reduce(`&`, list(df[-ncol(df)] < -1.7, df[-1] < -1.7))) > 0))
#[1] "1977" "1979" "1980" "1982" "1983" "1985"
```

Comment: many thanks for this. I have a new follow up question on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291153/return-rows-where-consecutive-values-meet-criterion-include-values-in-previous

Answer (score 3):

A fun option using `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE`

```
temp <- which(df < -1.7, arr.ind = TRUE)
rownames(df)[aggregate(col~row, temp, function(x) any(diff(x) == 1))[, 2]]

#[1] "1977" "1979" "1980" "1982" "1983" "1985"
```

We first get all row and column positions where value is less than -1.7. Using `aggregate` we group `col` for every `row` and check if there is at least one consecutive value in a row and for values which return `TRUE` subset its `rownames`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution which uses the **lagged sum** to get the sum of each pair of numbers in a vector. If the lagged sum gets 2, then it means at least 2 consecutive values in that row meet the condition.

```
rownames(df)[apply(df < -1.7, 1, function(x) any(x[-nrow(df)] + x[-1] == 2))]

# [1] "1977" "1979" "1980" "1982" "1983" "1985"
```