# Return rows where consecutive values meet criterion - include values in previous rows

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I would like to follow up on my recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132300/return-rows-where-consecutive-values-meet-criterion)

I have the following database and I am looking for rows which have a certain number consecutive values exceeding certain threshold, example:

In the following dataframe `df`. I would like to return a vector `result` that indicates which rows meet the following criterion: at least 5 consecutive values `consecutiveentries` in that row are lower than `threshold` -1.2.

```
set.seed(125)

df <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V2=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V3=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V4=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V5=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V6=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V7=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V8=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V9=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V10=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5))
rownames(df) <- c(seq(1976,1985,1))

threshold = -1.2
consecutiveentries = 5
number <- consecutiveentries-1

result <- as.numeric(names(which(apply(df, 1, function(x) with(rle(x < threshold), any(lengths[values] > number))))))

result
[1] 1985
```

Now I would like to take it step further. I would like to check for 5 consecutive numbers `consecutiveentries` with no row end limit. In other words, if in preceding row there are values below the `threshold` - for example 5 values are lower than `threshold` -1.2 at the end of row 1976 and 2 first values are below the `threshold` at the beginning of row 1977, then I would like to have a solution for three options. Either return the name of the second row where 5 consecutive values across two rows meet the criteria as `result2`, or the name of the first row as `result1`. Finally, return both values as `result3`.

Results would be following:

```
result1
    [1] 1976 1980 1983 1985
result2
    [1] 1977 1981 1984 1985
result3
    [1] 1976 1977 1980 1981 1983 1984 1985
```

Comment: what are the conditions you need to meet for all three outputs?

Comment: @Phi I need to return name of the row where 5 consecutive values are lower than -1.2. It can be in a row but also can also include values from the preceding row.